# event fired from clicking suggestion from form

Tags: jquery, forms, frontend

I'm trying to validate an email and have written a working function that is run everytime a key is pressed. The only problem is that when suggestions are presented and the user clicks one the function is not called as a keypress event is not emitted. Does anyone know the event that is emitted when a user clicks of a suggestion to autocomplete a form?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include relevant sections of your code. Also, are you using any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with validation code, as many browsers do not trigger a `change`, `keypress`, and other events when an option is chosen via autocomplete. You basically have two options here:

1. Disable autocomplete on the form, with `autocomplete="off"`
2. Run your validation on submit, rather than on `keypress`

Answer (score 0):

OK so this works for me when clicking on an autocomplete suggestion. Am using chrome tho and not sure about cross browser compatibility.

```
$('#email').bind('input', function(){ 

    console.log('bind');

    if(validateEmail($(this).attr('value'))){
        $('#correctemail').show();
        $('#incorrectemail').hide();
        console.log('true');
        validemail = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#incorrectemail').show();
        $('#correctemail').hide();
        console.log('false');
        validemail = false;
    }});
```